# In C++, is it possible to override a single data type in a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++builder

I wrote a sample application to point out what I am trying to do.  I have a template that I want to behave differently for a single data type and I would like to hide that from the calling program.  In the code below, the intention is that if the data type is UnicodeString, I want it to use my override function; otherwise, I want it to use the template.  It would also work to just modify the template and get rid of my override function, if that is possible.

If TRY_TO_OVERRIDE_TEMPLATE is defined, it looks like the compiler gives up because it can't decide which template to use.

If DO_NOT_EXPLICITLY_REFERENCE_TEMPLATE is defined, it causes a compile time error.

If neither of the defines are defined, it does a string concatenation, rather than converting each string to integer and adding the numerical values together.

I am using the current edition of C++ Builder, by the way.

```
//#define TRY_TO_OVERRIDE_TEMPLATE // results in "Unresolved external 'System::UnicodeString __fastcall MyMath::MyAddSystem::UnicodeString(System::UnicodeString, System::UnicodeString)' referenced from ...\UNIT1.OBJ" //#define DO_NOT_EXPLICITLY_REFERENCE_TEMPLATEclass MyMath {
public:
    MyMath() {};
    #ifdef TRY_TO_OVERRIDE_TEMPLATE
        template <typename T> UnicodeString __fastcall MyAdd(UnicodeString a, UnicodeString b);
    #else
        UnicodeString __fastcall MyAdd(UnicodeString a, UnicodeString b);
    #endif
    template <typename T> T __fastcall MyAdd(T a, T b);
};

#ifdef TRY_TO_OVERRIDE_TEMPLATE
    template <typename T> UnicodeString __fastcall MyAdd(UnicodeString a, UnicodeString b) {
        int intA = a.ToInt();
        int intB = b.ToInt();
        return UnicodeString(a + b);
    }
#else
    UnicodeString __fastcall MyAdd(UnicodeString a, UnicodeString b) {
        int intA = a.ToInt();
        int intB = b.ToInt();
        return UnicodeString(a + b);
    }
#endif

template <typename T> T __fastcall MyMath::MyAdd(T a, T b) {
    return a + b;     // When defined DO_NOT_EXPLICITLY_REFERENCE_TEMPLATE, this gives standard error concatinating UnicodeStrings ([bcc32c Error] Unit1.cpp(41): invalid operands to binary expression ('const wchar_t *' and 'const wchar_t *')
}

void __fastcall TForm1::cmdRunClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    UnicodeString txt;

    MyMath * mth = new MyMath();

    ComboBox1->Items->Add(L"1 + 3 =" + UnicodeString(mth->MyAdd<int>(1, 3)));
    ComboBox1->Items->Add(L"1.1 + 3.3 =" + UnicodeString(mth->MyAdd<double>(1.1, 3.3)));
    ComboBox1->Items->Add(L"2.2 + 4 =" + UnicodeString(mth->MyAdd<UnicodeString>(L"2.2", L"4")));  // result is "2.24" rather than "6"
    #ifdef DO_NOT_EXPLICITLY_REFERENCE_TEMPLATE
        ComboBox1->Items->Add(L"2.2 + 4 =" + UnicodeString(mth->MyAdd(L"2.2", L"4")));
    #endif
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are asking, you need to implement a template function  and then implement a template specialization for a concrete data type. Like `template<> UnicodeString MyAdd(int a, int b)`. Does that sound reasonable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on standard overloading rules. If you want a specific Add for Unicode strings then provide an overload next to the generic template you already have, and it will be selected at compile time.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

using namespace std::string_literals;

template<typename type_t>
auto add(const type_t& lhs, const type_t& rhs)
{
    std::cout << "Generic add : " << lhs << " + " << rhs << "\n";;
    return lhs + rhs;
}

// you can have non-template overloads too
// they will be selected in favor of the template
// when they match.
auto add(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
{
    auto result = std::format("String addition : '{}' + {}", lhs, rhs);
    std::cout << result << "\n";
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    add(1, 2);
    add("one"s, "two"s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I had thought, which is what should have happened when neither of my defines were defined.  I tried your sample code and modified it for C++ Builder.  It worked initially until I changed it to use the C++ Builder type UnicodeString.  Ultimately, I found that using {add(L"one", L"two");} failed but using {add((UnicodeString) "one", (UnicodeString) "two");} worked, so the problem was using the "L" prefix isn't really converting the string to a UnicodeString.

Comment: That's why I used the string literal ""s to create actual std::strings, types must match in this case because implicit conversions are only considered after the template match. So you would call the template with 2 wchar_t* arguments.